# How to disable scrolling in UITableView when the content fits the screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, tableview

How to disable scrolling behaviour in UITableView, when the content fits the screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

or this: if you don't want it to bounce:

```
tableView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO.
```

Comment: You can use interface builder to set scrollEnabled property.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
    tableView.bounces = NO;
```